# Combining values in python dictionaries without using Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to write this program without using Counter.Write a Python program to combine values in python list of dictionaries. Go to the editor
Sample data:

```
[{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400}, {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300}, {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]
**Expected Output: {'item1': 1150, 'item2': 300}**
```

So far here's my code.

```
a=[{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400}, {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300}, {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]    
cp={}
val=0
for d in a:
    if d['item'] not in cp:
        cp[d['item']]=d['amount']
print(cp)
```

My output:`{'item1': 400, 'item2': 300}`

How can I combined the total of of 'item1'?Any help is appreciated?

Comment: why would you handicap yourself by not using counter ... anyway counter is written in python and python is opensource and you can view its source to see how it does its update

Comment: Agree with JoranBeasley, you can easily look up source code for `Counter` & check where you are going wrong. Having said that, there are 2 defaultdict-ish based solutions below.

Comment: I am in automation QA,Sometimes in interview people ask not to write code in pythonic way rather they prefer  generic solution though it amazes me as well.Once I used enumerate to solve something in interview and interviewer got upset .

Comment: That's one bad interviewer.

Comment: @Rads, if one of the below solutions helped, consider accepting it (green tick on left) so other users know.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400}, {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300}, {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]    
cp={}
val=0
for d in a:
    if d['item'] not in cp:
        cp[d['item']] = d['amount']
    else:
        cp[d['item']] += d['amount'] 
print(cp)
```

Comment: It was my first post on stack overflow .thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400},
       {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300},
       {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}]

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in lst:
    d[i['item']] += i['amount']

# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'item1': 1150, 'item2': 300})
```

Comment: What is defaultdict ?

Comment: `defaultdict` allows you to set a default value for every key. That's why we can say `d[my_key] += 1` to increment a value by 1 *even when the key has not been explicitly set*. The defaultvalue for int is 0, so if you looking for the value of a key not set, you will find 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for a_dict in all_my_dicts:
    for key in a_dict:
       d[key] = d.get(key,0)+a_dict[key]
```

I guess maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` here.

```
from collections import defaultdict
for d in l:
    data[d['item']] += d['amount']

Out[72]: defaultdict(int, {'item1': 1150, 'item2': 300})
```